# See the changes you are making live on Hostgator

Tags: php, server, subdomain

I am learning PHP and was wondering if there was a way of me seeing the changes I am making in the php file live on my Hostgator server?

I have a subdomain set up but every time I learn something new and try to test with it I am uploading the new file via Hostgator cPanel. Is there a better way?

Comment: Test it in your local and upload. it's a common way. **There is no any Rocket Science on this**

Comment: Hi Abdulla, thanks for the reply. I have been using localhost up until now, but as far as I am aware, I think there are some things that you can't test via localhost like setting up emails if someone subscribes, right?